# TortoiseSVN external issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, external

Recently, I have been bothered by an external-related SVN issue after adjusting my project's structures. I need some help. Here is my scenario:

I have a folder structure like this:

> \MyProject\Mydata

Under **Mydata** folder, I have an external

> \MyProject\Mydata\res

which links to another res folder under one old project.

Now, this new project needs its own **res** folder. So I removed the external and committed it. Then I removed the local **res** folder (the working copy), and created a new **res** folder, then added and committed this new **res** folder.

After that, when updating under **Mydata** folder, I can pull down the latest data and files in the **res** folder (the new project its own) successfully. However, it also comes with some unexpected *'actions'* and *'errors'* showing in my SVN dialog saying:

> Deleting    d:\MyProject\Mydata\res

> External failed    d:\MyProject\Mydata\res

> Error    'd:\MyProject\Mydata\res' is already locaked via 'd:\MyProject'

> Error    Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.

I checked *'Propeties'* under **Mydata** folder and I am sure that there is no external information there. And after executing *'Cleanup'* command, these annoying messages still come up when I do updating each time.

I wonder whether this is a real error or not. How can I fix the error or remove these faked error messages? Does anybody have similar experience before?

By the way, my TortoiseSVN version is 1.9.2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you commit the property modification of **Mydata** folder ?